# Suggested reading for BITS/Bytes and sample code to perform operations etc

Tags: binary, byte, hex

Need a refresher on bits/bytes, hex notation and how it relates to programming (C# preferred).

Looking for a good reading list (online preferably).

Answer (score 2):

There are several layers to consider here:

- Electronic

In the electronic paradigm, everything is a wire.

A single wire represents a single bit.

0 is the LOW voltage, 1 is the
HIGH voltage. The voltages may be `[0,5], [-3.3, 3], [-5, 5], [0, 1.3]`,
etc. The key thing is that there are only two voltage levels which control
the action of the transistors.

A byte is a collection of wires(To be precise, it's probably collected in a set of flip-flops called registers, but let's leave it as "wires" for now).

- Programming

A bit is 0 or 1.

A byte is - in modern systems - 8 bits. Ancient systems might have had 10-bit bytes or other sizes; they don't exist today.

A *nybble* is 4 bits; half a byte.

Hexadecimal is an efficient representation of 8 bits.  For example: F
maps to `1111 1111`. That is more efficient than writing 15. Plus, it is quite clear if you are writing down multiple byte values: FF is unambiguous; 1515 can be read several different ways.

Historically, octal has been also used(base 8). However, the only place where I have met it is in the Unix permissions.

Since on the electronic layer, it is most efficient to collect memory
in groups of 2^n, hex is a natural notation for representing
memory. Further, if you happen to work at the driver level, you may
need to specifically control a given bit, which will require the use
of bit-level operators. It is clear which bytes are on HI if you say
`F & outputByte` than `15 & outputByte`.

In general, much of modern programming does not need to concern itself
with binary and hexadecimal. However, if you are in a place where you
need to know it, there is no slipping by - you *really* need to know
it then.

Particular areas that need the knowledge of binary include: embedded
systems, driver writing, operating system writing, network protocols,
and compression algorithms.

While you wanted C#, C# is really not the right language for bit-level
manipulation. Traditionally, C and C++ are the languages used for bit
work. Erlang works with bit manipulation, and Perl supports it as
well. VHDL is completely bit-oriented, but is fairly difficult to work
with from the typical programming perspective.

Here is some sample C code for performing different logical operations:

```
char a, b, c;  
c = a ^ b;      //XOR
c = a & b;      //AND
c = a | b;      //OR
c = ~(a & b);   //NOT AND(NAND)
c = ~a;         //NOT
c = a << 2;     //Left shift 2 places
c = a >> 2;     //Right shift 2 places.
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit is either 1 or 0.

A byte is 8 bits.

Each character in hex is 4 bits represented as 0-F

- 0000 is 0
- 0001 is 1
- 0010 is 2
- 0011 is 3
- ...
- 1110 is E
- 1111 is F

There's a pretty good intro to C#'s bit-munching operations [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/chandrahundigam/BitWiserOpsInCS11082005050940AM/BitWiserOpsInCS.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some basic reading: http://www.learn-c.com/data_lines.htm

Bits and bytes hardly ever relates to C# since the CLR handles memory by itself. There are classes and methods handling hex notation and all those things in the framework too. But, it is still a fun read.

Answer (score 0):

[Write Great Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593270038) is a good primer on this topic among others...brings you from the bare metal to higher order languages.